# How to insert an ancestor and sibling for an element using xpath in perl?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, perl-module

I want to insert an ancestor and sibling for an element using xpath in perl.

**This is my input**

```
<docinfo:hier>
<docinfo:hierlev role="ancestor">
<heading>
<title>CENTRAl</title>
</heading>
<docinfo:hierlev role="ancestor">
<heading>
<title>A</title>
</heading>
<docinfo:hierlev role="ancestor">
<heading><title>AC</title></heading>
<docinfo:hierlev role="ancestor">
<heading><title>THE ACTUARIE</title></heading>
<docinfo:hierlev role="ancestor">
<heading><title>CHAPTER VII </title></heading>
<docinfo:hierlev role="me">
<heading>
<title>46. Terms and conditions of Chairman and Members of Board.</title>             
</heading>
</docinfo:hierlev>
</docinfo:hierlev>
</docinfo:hierlev>
</docinfo:hierlev>
</docinfo:hierlev>
</docinfo:hierlev>
```

**I want output like this:**

`##` Represents newly inserted element

```
<docinfo:hier>
<docinfo:hierlev role="ancestor">
<heading><title>Rules</title></heading># here i want change the text
<docinfo:hierlev role="ancestor">##
<heading>##
<title>Rule</title>##
</heading>##
<docinfo:hierlev role="ancestor">
<heading><title>A</title></heading>
<docinfo:hierlev role="ancestor">
<heading><title>AC</title></heading>
<docinfo:hierlev role="ancestor">
<heading><title>THE ACTUARIE</title></heading>
<docinfo:hierlev role="ancestor">
<heading><title>CHAPTER VII </title></heading>
<docinfo:hierlev role="me">
<heading>
<title>46. Terms and conditions of Chairman and Members of Board.</title>
</heading>
</docinfo:hierlev>
</docinfo:hierlev>
</docinfo:hierlev>
</docinfo:hierlev>
</docinfo:hierlev>
</docinfo:hierlev>##
</docinfo:hierlev>
</docinfo:hier>
```

**This is my source code**

When I run the code it inserts only the element title.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new;
my $doc = $parser->parse_file("mytest.xml");
my $root = $doc->getDocumentElement();
my ($ref_node) = $doc->findnodes('/LEGDOC/docinfo/docinfo:hier/docinfo:hierlev/heading');

my $new_element= $doc->createElement("docinfo:hierlev");
my $new_element= $doc->createElement("heading");
my $new_element= $doc->createElement("title");
$new_element->appendText('rule');
$ref_node->parentNode->insertAfter($new_element, $ref_node);

print $root->toString(1);
```

Comment: You're declaring `$new_element` three times. This would have generated a warning.

Comment: hi friedo thanks for the suggession  i have changed the variable name and but also its not working

Answer (score 0):

As Friedo suggested above instead of adding each element to the $new_element variable you are overwriting it.

My Perl is a bit rusty but I think you would need something along the lines of the below.  I am aware this could be done in less lines of code but I have tried to keep the steps separate for clarity.

```
  -- create distinct nodes for each level
  my $newDocInfoElement = $doc->createElement("docinfo:hierlev");
  my $newHeadingElement = $doc->createElement("heading");
  my $newTitleElement = $doc->createElement("title");
  $newTitleElement->appendText('rule');

  --append them into the structure that you want
  $newHeadingElement->addChild($newTitleElement);
  $newDocInfoElement->addChild($newHeadingElement);

  --add the whole structure to your XML
  $ref_node->parentNode->insertAfter($newDocInfoElement, $ref_node);
```

Hope this is Helpfull.

Comment: it creates an element but it doesnt become an ancestor for next docinfo:hierlev

Comment: I don't have a system I can test this on currently so it was done from memory. My best advise is to have a look at some of the methods at http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod and try a few to see if you can get it working.